# Lower bound of Erdős–Szekeres conjecture

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

To put things short, what is a practical construction of $2^{n-2}$ points that contain no n-gon?

The lower bound for the Erdős–Szekeres number is  $2^{n-2}+1$, the argument is that it is possible to construct a set of $2^{n-2}$ points without an n-gon. As I am searching for such construction, all paper directed to the paper *On some extremum problems in elementary geometry* by Erdős and Szekeres in 1960's. However, the online version of this paper I found have the pages about the construction removed, I attempt to program a construction based on a physical copy of this paper. I found the first part of that construction not really working, the recurrence definition will always returns zero, there must be a misprint in the paper. (I also attempted to change the initial conditions for the recurrence, but I still cannot get a set of points I desired.)

Then I attempt to search for other constructions, but I cannot find any detailed version of such a construction that I can actually graph with. The underlying idea of the proof should be correct, but I do not know how to modify the definition to construct a set I desired. Can anyone show me a practical construction of $2^{n-2}$ points, so that I can try to graph it? It would also be helpful if someone can show me a plot of 32 points with no 7-gon.

Comment: The version of the paper in *Paul Erdős: The Art of Counting* also isn't missing the pages. (Not relevant to you since you have a physical copy, but other people with this problem might find tracking down the book easier.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the misprint in the paper can be fixed by changing the initial condition from $g_{1l}(1) = g_{k1}(1) = 0$ to $g_{1l}(1) = g_{k1}(1) = 1$. I don't think this is actually where the misprint occurred, since the value of $0$ is consistent with a later example, but this change makes the construction work anyway.

Also, in a later step, I believe the definition of $S_k$ only makes sense if it says
$$
   S_k = S_{k,n-k} + \left(\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} (n-i)a_i, -\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}a_i\right), \qquad 1\le k \le n-1
$$
rather than a similar definition of of $S_{k+1}$.

Anyway, the problem is that the nature of the construction makes the result entirely unplottable. Here is what I get when I plot the $32$ points for $n=7$:

[image: erdos-szekeres]

The reason for this is that the explicit constants used in the construction can all be replaced by "make this constant large enough for such and such property to hold", and so the only thing you see in this picture is the clusters of points corresponding to the set $S_1, S_2, \dots, S_6$. If you zoomed in on $S_3$ (which is a translate of $S_{3,4}$) you would see two clusters of points: one which is a translate of $S_{2,4}$, and one which is a translate of $S_{3,3}$; once again, the distance between these would be much bigger than the distance between points within a cluster.

If it helps, the coordinates of the $32$ points I got are:

`{{1,1},{16135,-2688},{16136,-2686},{16137,-2679},{16138,-2648},{16139,-2483},{63595,-12180},{63596,-12171},{63597,-12169},{63598,-12108},{63599,-12106},{63600,-12099},{63601,-11360},{63602,-11358},{63603,-11351},{63604,-11320},{96151,-20319},{96152,-20271},{96153,-20262},{96154,-20260},{96155,-19499},{96156,-19490},{96157,-19488},{96158,-19427},{96159,-19425},{96160,-19418},{109624,-24810},{109625,-24510},{109626,-24462},{109627,-24453},{109628,-24451},{111766,-25881}}`

(Whether or not the construction's good in general, I can confirm that these $32$ points definitely don't contain a convex heptagon - tested by brute force.)

Comment: Thank you. I re-examined the code and graph I got earlier, I think the definition of $S_{k}$ is the key to get the correct points. (With the definition of $S_{k}$  as written in the paper, the last cluster would contain more than one points, which was my main confusion.)